# Abrir navegador en VS Code (Jupyter)

Tags: python, jupyter, navegador-web

cree un proyecto en vs code con jupyter y funciona pero no logro correrlo en algun navegador ya intente agregar el launch.json , agregando jupyter a las variables de entorno de sistema pero no hay caso.  comparto imagenes del archivo "prueba.ipynb"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y el codigo del launch.json

{`"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
{
"name": "Launch Program",
"program": "${workspaceFolder}/app.js",
"request": "launch",
"skipFiles": [
"<node_internals>/**"
],
"type": "pwa-node"
},
{
"name": "Attach",
"port": 9229,
"request": "attach",
"skipFiles": [
"<node_internals>/**"
],
"type": "pwa-node"
},
{
"name": "Attach by Process ID",
"processId": "${command:PickProcess}",
"request": "attach",
"skipFiles": [
"<node_internals>/**"
],
"type": "pwa-node"
},

```
    {
        "type": "pwa-chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
        "url": "https://localhost:8080",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
    
]`
```

}

Comment: Tan pronto termine de tipear las imágenes te ofreceré una solución. Me voy a demorar, porque seguramente transcribiré mal alguna de las imágenes. En fin, tendré que revisar dos veces. Paciencia.

Comment: Llevas dos meses apuntado en este sitio y aún no has realizado el [tour] para aprender cómo funciona. Te invito ha hacerlo ahora y así aprenderás a realizar buenas preguntas. Léete tambien [ask] para ello. Las imágenes con código no son bien recibidas porque no nos permiten copiar y pegar y nos impiden ayudarte bien (sino mira al pobre @CandidMoe que después de 12 horas lo sigue intentando, se merece una medalla o dos!). Por favor, copia tu código y peǵalo como texto para recibir mejor ayuda, gracias.